# Maven PluginManagement Variable Binding from Parent POM

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-plugin, grpc-java

Can you help me understand why I cannot put my `<pluginMangement>` config on my parent POM?

I have this `<pluginMangement>` config. When it is in the parent POM, my build fails
because the `<pluginArtifact>` incorrectly resolves to:

```
io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.23.0:exe:linux-x86_64
```

When it is in my POM, the `<pluginArtifact>` correctly resolves to

```
io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.23.0:exe:osx-x86_64
```

In my local POM, I use this build extension:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

## `<pluginMangement>` config

(Note dynamic `<pluginArtifact>`)

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <!-- http://os72.github.io/protoc-jar-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html -->
  <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
  <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${protoc-jar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>generate-sources</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <addProtoSources>all</addProtoSources>
              <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
              <includeMavenTypes>transitive</includeMavenTypes>
              <includeDirectories>
                  <include>src/main/proto</include>
              </includeDirectories>
              <inputDirectories>
                  <include>src/main/proto</include>
              </inputDirectories>
              <protocArtifact>
                  com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
              </protocArtifact>
              <outputTargets>
                  <outputTarget>
                      <type>java</type>
                  </outputTarget>
                  <outputTarget>
                      <type>grpc-java</type>
                      <pluginArtifact>
                          io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                      </pluginArtifact>
                  </outputTarget>
              </outputTargets>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When the configuation is on the parent, the `os.detected.classifier` shows correct at the start of the build:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: osx
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
...
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: osx-x86_64
```

But then the plugin shows to resolve to the incorrect artifact:

```
[INFO] --- protoc-jar-maven-plugin:3.8.0:run (generate-sources) @ recipe-order-processor ---
[INFO] Resolving artifact: com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:linux-x86_64, platform: osx-x86_64
```

I suspect the issue is due to when inherited variables on managed plugins are bound, but I can't find any Apache Maven references to "binding order" regarding `<pluginMangement>` on parent POMs.

Comment: Also, if I run:
`mvn clean compile`
…the build fails at `protoc-jar-maven-plugin`.
If I run:
`mvn protoc-jar`
then the plugin resolves correctly.

Comment: I also put a break point in the `protoc-jar-maven-plugin`; by the time it is invoked, the variables from the plugin `<configuration>` have been resolved/bound to (the incorrect) `linux-x86_64` arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get `os.detected.classifier` to resolve correctly when using `os-maven-plugin`, you need to use it as a plugin not an extension. For some reason, if you use it as an extension in the parent POM, it will resolve to the platform that that parent POM was compiled on. Be careful to be sure that none of you dependencies inherit from a parent pom that defines `os-maven-plugin` as an extension.

The documentation doesn't mention parent POM inheritance as a reason to configure `os-maven-plugin` as a plugin, but here is what it does say about how.

https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin#issues-with-eclipse-m2e-or-other-ides

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>detect</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```